# Update/override javascript function which is in "WebResource.axd"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using one 3rd party control for grid filters(By adding DLL reference). 
While applying filters to my grid, calling JavaScript method `igtbl_filterTypeSelect(event).` I have identify this in `WebResource.axd` (DOM inspect element)

I want to customize this `igtbl_filterTypeSelect(event)` function. So, is there any way to override or can I update this function/bypass this from my page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the 3rd party control?

Comment: Its Infragistics

Comment: When you override this function, what do you want to do inside the function?